# VDI not detecting any virtual machines

Tags: remote-desktop, virtualization, vdi

When I try to create a Virtual Desktop collection in server 2012 r2 remote desktop services, the setup process does not detect any of the virtual machines that I have created and sysprepped. Its in a lab environment, the Domain Controller, Hyper-V manager and the VDI is on the same server. can anyone help me with it?

Answer (score 0):

You create a template from the shutdown and sysprep'd VM. It is the template that shows up in the collection. Follow the lab for some basics:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh831585.aspx

Comment: can you please tell me how i can create a template of this vm ?